# Is there a way, when declaring a variable to limit its possible values?

Tags: vba, integer, limit

```
Dim MyInt As Integer

Sub Test()
    MyInt = 14
End Sub
```

I want the variable MyInt to be lower than 16, always. Is there a way, when I declare it to limit the possible values assignation?
Maybe using another type?

Comment: Declare it as a property. This way you have to option to check its value before assignment and take action if the criteria is not met.

Comment: ...or if you're not working in an object-type code module then create a (eg) `SetMyInt` method/Sub which you use to set the value instead of a direct assignment. That method then checks the assigned value.